# JQUERY SUBMIT HANDLER cause error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

It's just a piece of code...But its not posting any value to the corresponding PHP file..I checked with `print_r` statement...

I tried my own ideas...I won't work anymore..

Any possibilities?

Awaiting for solution...

Thanks in advance.

**FORM**(Updated)

```
<form method="post" id="book-appointment">

  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = &#39;&#39;" 
         onblur="if (this.value==&#39;&#39;) this.value = this.defaultValue" placeholder="Name" />
  <br />

  <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" 
         onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = &#39;&#39;"
         onblur="if (this.value==&#39;&#39;) this.value = this.defaultValue" />
  <br />

  <input name="email" type="text" id="email"
         onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = &#39;&#39;" 
         onblur="if (this.value==&#39;&#39;) this.value = this.defaultValue" placeholder="Email" />
  <br>          
  <input type="submit" value="ENQUIRE NOW" class="btn btn-block has-spinner" style="background: #c2002f; color: #ffffff;
                              font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase; border-bottom: none; margin: 10px 0px;
                              padding: 12px 0 10px 0px;" />
  <div class="alert" style="text-align: center;padding: 8px;display: none;" id="alert_enquiry">Please Wait...</div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT FILE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#book-appointment").validate({
        rules:
                {
                    name: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    phone: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true
                    }
                },
        messages:
                {
                    name: "Please enter your name",
                    email: "Please enter the mail address",
                    phone: "Please enter the phone number",
                },
        submitHandler: submitForm
    });
    function submitForm()
    {
        var data = $("#book-appointment").serialize();
        var url = "user_detail.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                var btn = $(this);
                $(btn).buttonLoader('start');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(btn).buttonLoader('stop');
                }, 3000);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    //windows.location.href="thank.php";
                    window.location.href = 'thankyou.php';
                }, 2000);

                $('#name').val('');
                $('#phone').val('');
                $('#email').val('');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I can't find the problem.?

Comment: show your html form

Comment: There's too little information. Some debug info from developer tools (network tab / console) would be nice. There are too many things that could go wrong - sending request, accessing the url, parsing on php side, javascript runtime error...

Comment: Any error? If yes, please paste that error too.

Comment: It shows No errors bro